# Get keyboard language on Windows

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout

I know that I can use the [GetKeyboardLayout function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646296(v=vs.85).aspx) in order to retrieve the current keyboard language.
However I am still confused on how to use the return value of this function.

Can someone write down a practical example on how to use it, for example, to check if keyboard is set to English language? (I'm using C++)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: if (PRIMARYLANGID(hkl & 0xffff) == LANG_ENGLISH)

Comment: @HansPassant, thank you for your response.
Actually I don't think what you wrote is totally correct, since I get an error ("expression must have integral or unscoped enum type") but it definitely pointed me in the right direction. 
In my Visual C++ it seem to work correctly this way:
if (PRIMARYLANGID(KeyboardLayout) == LANG_ENGLISH)

Comment: Well, don't tell me, just post the correct code to complete your Q+A and accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution!

```
HKL KeyboardLayout = GetKeyboardLayout(0);
if (PRIMARYLANGID(KeyboardLayout) == LANG_ENGLISH)
```